# Automatically check for iPad app when downloading specific file type from website?

Tags: ios, ipad

I think I already know the answer to this ("can't be done"), but I figured I'd see what people think...

On my client's website they're posting files for download that specifically need to be viewed on iPads using the Cadwork Viewer app:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cadwork-viewer/id505161598?mt=8

You can't open the file on an iPad unless you have that app, and I'm wondering if when clicking on the file to initiate download if there's a way to scan the device to see if Cadwork Viewer is already installed.  If so, proceed with the download of the file.  If not, pop up a notice "This file requires the Cadwork Viewer app, download it here from iTunes."  Something like that.

Again, I think this is just not doable, but hey...there's all sorts of things I don't know!

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this link:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html

You can add a banner to the mobile site that lets you open the app from Safari.

Explanation from Apple:

> If the app is already installed on a user's device, the banner
>   intelligently changes its action, and tapping the banner will simply
>   open the app. If the user doesn’t have your app on his device, tapping
>   on the banner will take him to the app’s entry in the App Store.

This should be a good starting place.

Comment: Excellent, thanks!  Possibly not a full solution for what I'm looking for, but as you said definitely a good place to start.